# Classification using Matlab neural networks toolbox - image input?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have the images of 4 different animals and need to do classification using the Matlab neural networks toolbox. In Matlab's examples (Iris), the form of input data is a 4*1 vector (sepal width, etc..), but I want the input to be the original images. In other words I want the neural networks to extract the features for the images (e.g. the kernels in convolutional NN), not myself using something like color histogram or SIFT. Is it possible for the toolbox to do the job? Thanks.